# Proof irrelevance (2)

Tags: coq

Let's assume we have two proofs for a simple lemma.

```
   Lemma l1: exists x:nat, x <> 0.
    exists 1.
    intro.
    discriminate.
    Defined.

    Lemma l2: exists x:nat, x <> 0.
    exists 2.
    discriminate.
    Defined.
```

Intuitively, I would say that those are two different proofs.
So, can I prove the following lemma?

```
Lemma l3: l1 <> l2
```

I suppose this is undecidable.
What happens if we introduce the Univalence Axiom ?

Answer (score 4):

First, a small note on terminology. There is another sense of "undecidable" often used in theoretical computer science to refer to problems of deciding, given an  *arbitrary* element of some set, whether a fixed property holds or not of that element. If there is an algorithm computable by, say, a Turing machine, that correctly answers the question for any possible input, we say the problem is *decidable*; otherwise, it is *undecidable*. Your notion of "undecidable" is often referred to as "[independence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(mathematical_logic))" (The two issues are of course, related.  The problem of whether an *arbitrary* Coq proposition is provable or not is undecidable.)

Now, back to your question. I believe (although I am not entirely sure) that your lemma `l3` cannot be proved or refuted in Coq even if you incorporate the univalence axiom. The reason is that the univalence axiom only violates proof irrelevance for a particular kind of proposition: equality assertions. And there is nothing about it that has any obvious consequences for existential quantification. Perhaps some intuition here can help. There is a computationally relevant analog of existential quantification (that is, something that lives in `Type`) that allows you to prove your principle, independently of assuming univalence:

```
Lemma l1: { x:nat | x <> 0 }.
  exists 1.
  intro.
  discriminate.
Defined.

Lemma l2: { x:nat | x <> 0 }.
  exists 2.
  discriminate.
Defined.

Lemma l3: l1 <> l2.
Proof.
  intros H. inversion H.
Qed.
```

However, even if this is possible for this type, it is still safe to assume irrelevance for existential quantification, because Coq's logic prevents us from manipulating its proofs in a way that allow us to extract which witnesses were used.

Comment: Great answer Arthur! An additional funny fact is that the choice principle  `exists x : nat, x <> 0 -> {x : nat | x <> 0 }` is required to pick the same witness for `l1` and `l2`.

Comment: That sounds interesting! Could you elaborate?

Comment: @ejgallego Did you mean `(exists x : nat, x <> 0) -> {x : nat | x <> 0 }`?